Why is a loop device called a "loop" device?
As far as I understand, a loop device is a regular file that acts as a block device.
It's used for various things like isolation in snap packages and installing ISOs over an existing filesystem.
But why is it called a "loop" device?
Is there any "looping" that actually occurs?
Is this a case where the term is misleading and does not describe the true nature of the abstraction?

I'm sure someone more knowledgeable will explain all there is to it, personally I've always read it as in "whatever is supposed to interact with this won't interact with a block device, and will instead be "redirected" back to something else", which somehow reacalls the action of "looping back", as the layer of indirection makes it so you're not really done with whatever you were doing, and you sort of have to start over (not really, it's done automatically, but you get what I mean). Maybe it's just my personal interpretation shrug

If you think of the regular stack of filesystem>device, the variant with a mounted image file is something like filesystem>(loop) device>filesystem>(real) device, so in a way, the loop device makes device accesses "loop back" to the filesystem layer. Or something like that anyway, and if that doesn't seem to make sense, try to not think about the origins too much; the descriptive names for different concepts don't always make sense for everyone. Frankly, I also have questions about "loopback" interfaces in relation to networking...

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device

@AaronD.Marasco why are those links relevant? Neither of them explain why these are called loop devices or where the "loop" is coming from.

@terdon : """ In Solaris/OpenSolaris, the loop device is called "loopback file interface" """

i thought this is called loop device, like the loop back device in network, sending data to this network devices comes back and so on and so on,  every access of a file inside an image file is an access back on this image file. But i dont know, this is a self rhyme

@AaronD.Marasco yes, so why loop?
